# Create a custom plugin on ckeditor for angular application

Tags: angular, plugins, ckeditor5

I need to create a custom plugin for ckeditor to allow users to create a cutom html a element.

I managed to create this plugin on small project including my code in script element like in the ckeditor examples (following this : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html). Everything ok.

But my problem is to include the plugin in my Angular application. I don't understand how to import it.

I tried many different ways to import the built ckeditor.js file generated by webpack, but never worked...

So my main issue is that i don't understand how to get from the simple project generating a build with my plugin inside to import it in my Angular application..

Thanks if someone have an idea to solve this ??

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out ?

Comment: I didn't figure it out, but I try your solution on next monday, i'm not at work now. thanks !

Answer (score 13):

I found out how to do it.

1. clone the `ckeditor5-build-classic`

   ```
   git clone -b stable https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5.git
   cd ckeditor5/packages/ckeditor5-build-classic/
   ```
2. install dependencies and any other plugins you may want to add (alignment for instance)

   `npm i npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment`
3. update `src/ckeditor.js` with added plugin(s)

`import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';`

```
    // Plugins to include in the build.
    ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
        ...
        Alignment                                                            
    ];
```

4. run `npm run build`to package the new build
5. copy the file `build/ckeditor.js` to the asset folder in you angular application
6. This is how you import the file (path may vary depending on your setup) :

`import * as CustomEditor from '@app/../assets/ckeditor.js';`

Finally in your component just declare the editor like this :

`public Editor = CustomEditor;`

Comment: Hi, following your way is ok for me too, but, i want to do this adding a custom plugin like in this example : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html 
Alignment is a ckeditor stuff, i need to create my own one.

Comment: OMG! It is really that simple! I was banging my head reading the docs at ckeditor website wondering if I really had to go through all that stuff just to add 'underline' and 'alignment'. It all seemed very confusing and complicated for someone like me who never tried this before. Thanks a million. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide the config option also.

[Please check this link](https://medium.com/@vikramsaurabh4/setting-up-ckeditor-with-angular-10-69765423ecd3)